# Пример связи “один-ко-многим”

Tags: база-данных

Что она значит? Приведите, пожалуйста, пример, когда эту связь нужно устанавливать. Лучше пример из жизни, когда такая связь осуществляется.

И как мне записать в БД, что у одного объекта имеются несколько значений?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPD. Пример. Пусть будут два вида пользователей:

Авторы - могут создавать посты;
Редакторы - могут дополнять и редактировать посты (чем то похоже на ru.SO).
Таким образом получается следующие отношения: Один-Ко-Многим между автором и постами и Многие-Ко-Многим между редакторами и постами. Таблицы будут следующие:
users

```
id | name
---+------
1  | Vasya
2  | Petya
3  | Vanya

    post
id | title | autor_id | text
---+-------+----------+---------------
1  | PHP   | 1        | Blah-blah-blah

    post_editor
user_id | post_id
--------+---------
2       | 1
3       | 1
```

Таким образом можем увидеть, что пост PHP создал Vasya, а редактировали Petya и Vanya (отношение Многие-Ко-Многим реализуется через второстепенную таблицу).

Answer (score 3):

> пример связи один-ко-многим – это связь, которая существует между
>   матерью и ее детьми. Мать может иметь множество детей, но каждый
>   ребенок может иметь только одну мать.

https://habrahabr.ru/post/193380/